# Fastest way to determine offset in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

If I have an array of arbitrary length. How can I find what offset for a given element of that array would be if number of elements per slice is known? I mean without actually slicing the array.

Example:

```
arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, ..n]

if perSlice = 4; offset for arr[5] == 1, for arr[8] == 2 etc.
if perSlice = 3; offset for arr[2] = 0, for arr[4] = 1 etc.

i.e.: 

perSlice = 4
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, ..n]
 0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  2  2  2,  ..n
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the offset at index i by doing: `parseInt(i/perSlice)`

```
var arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

function getIndexes(arry, perSlice) {
  var ret =[];
  for(i in arry){
    ret.push(parseInt(i/perSlice));
  }
  return ret;
}

var indexes = getIndexes(arr, 4);
console.log(indexes);
```

EDIT: Note this uses the value at index i, not the index itself. Code is easily modifiable to use index instead of value.

Comment: updated with code to generate the array you want (as I understand it)

Comment: nah, I don't need generated array. It was shown just to explain better what I needed. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use [**indexOf**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), and take that [**modulo**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators) "perSlice"

```
var arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, ..n]
var perSlice = 4;
arr.indexOf(5) % perSlice
```

If you want to know WHICH slice the element ends up in, divide instead of %.

```
Math.floor(arr.indexOf(5) / perSlice) // 1
```

Comment: Or, you meant index after ONE Array.prototype.slice? In that case, subtract the perSlice instead of %.

Comment: Ah, you meant "which slice would the element end up in". See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Use the modulus operator

```
var arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, ..n]

       arr[(((index + step) % arr.length) + arr.length) % arr.length];
```